# Lifecycle.tick called recursively

Tags: angular

I am trying to have a component representing an item model. This compenents fetches the item then display it. I am trying to have childeren components that fetch some other properties of the item and display them. Unfortunately, this causes `Lifecycle.tick()` to be called recursively.

Take the following example:

```
@Component{selector: 'comp2', properties: ['item']}
@View{template: '<ul *ng-if="fetchedAttributes != null"><li *ng-for="#attribute of fetchedAttributes"> {{ attribute.name }} </li></ul>',
      directives: [NgIf, NgFor]}
export class Comp2 implements OnInit {
   fetchedAttributes: null;
   item: Item;

   onInit() {
     this.fetchAttributesPromise(this.item)
      .then((attributes)=>{this.fetchedAttribues = attributes;});
   }
}

@Component{selector: 'comp1'}
@View{template: '<comp2 *ng-if="fetchedItem != null" [item]="fetchedItem"></comp2>',
      directives: [Comp2, NgIf]}
export class Comp1 {
  fetchedItem: Item;
  constructor() {
     this.doFetchItem();
  }

  doFetchItem() {
    this.doFetchPromise()
    .then((item)=>{this.fetchedItem = item;});
  }
}
```

Comp1 fetches the item. When the result is fetched, a new Comp2 instance is created, it's `item` property is bound to the fetched item instance and it's `onInit` hook is called. This in turn create another request to fetch the item attributes, which result in an exception:

```
EXCEPTION: LifeCycle.tick is called recursively
Error: LifeCycle.tick is called recursively
    at new BaseException (angular2.js:4688)
    at execute.LifeCycle.tick (angular2.js:8741)
    at angular2.js:8736
    at Zone.run (zone.js?v=0.0.0:113)
    at Zone.execute.$__5._createInnerZone.zone.fork.fork.$run [as run] (angular2.js:9041)
    at XMLHttpRequest.zoneBoundFn (zone.js?v=0.0.0:86)
```

How can I cascade requests across multiple components without running into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a service to perform all requests.
You can have a view-scoped service instance if it is injected in the view bindings:

```
@Component({
//...
bindings: ['MyViewScopedService']
})
```

In this case the service will be available to all view children.

Or you can have an app-scoped service instance if you bind it upon 
bootstraping your app:

```
bootstrap(App, [
    MyAppScopedService,
    //...
]);
```

To use it, inject it in your constructors:

```
class ServiceConsumer {
 constructor(myService: MyViewScopedService) {
 }
}
```

Then cascade requests in your service.